# Having name of a function to be changed "i" times and then run in a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 3 **ARGUMENTLESS** functions called `f1`, `f2`, and, `f3`. So, simply `f1()` will run `f1` function, `f2()` will run `f2` function and so on.

**Question:**

I was wondering how I could have a simple `for(i in 1:3)` loop that runs f1 through f3?

I have tried the following with no succuss:

```
f1 = function() plot( rnorm(1e2) ); f2 = function() plot( rnorm(1e3) ); 
f3 = function() plot( rnorm(1e4) )


for (i in 1:3) {

 paste("f", i, "()", sep = "")

 Sys.sleep(1)

}
```

Comment: You may need `get`

Comment: Posted as a solution

Comment: Or another option is `lapply(mget(paste0("f", 1:3)), function(x) x())`

Comment: @akrun, yes akrun, except that using lapply `Sys.sleep` can't be incorporated.

Comment: Yes, you are rigth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `do.call` in your `for` loop:

```
for (i in 1:3) {

  do.call(paste0("f", i), args=list())

}
```

`do.call` takes the name of a function as a character string and a `list` of arguments, and executes the function.

Comment: Shorter, a bit: `eval(call(paste0("f", i)))`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `get` to get the function from the global environment

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    get(paste("f", i, sep = ""), envir = .GlobalEnv)()
    Sys.sleep(1)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
f1 <- function() plot( rnorm(1e2) )
f2 <- function() plot( rnorm(1e3) ) 
f3 <- function() plot( rnorm(1e4) )
for (i in 1:3) {

 get(paste0("f", i))()

 Sys.sleep(1)

}
```

anyway you could also start by putting all your functions into a list aka:

```
fun_list <- list(f1 = function() plot( rnorm(1e2) ),
                 f2 = function() plot( rnorm(1e3) ), 
                 f3 = function() plot( rnorm(1e4) ))
```

and then just loop through the list.